# Is there a way to run multiple %run statements in one line?

Tags: python, databricks

I have multiple %run statements currently in multiple lines in my databricks python notebook that work when running them one at a time. I was wondering if there was a way to combine them into one cell so that I don't have to run each individually. I have tried putting them together but keep getting errors

```
%run {location of file}
%run {location of file}
...
%run {location of file}
```

Error:

```
Failed to parse %run command: string matching regex `\$[\w_]+' expected but `%' found)
```

Below is what I tried based off OneCricketeer's suggestion. Turns out this solution doesn't resolve the issue.

```
notebooks = [
  ('{location of file}'),
  ('{location of file}'),
  ('{location of file}')]

for n in notebooks:
    dbutils.notebook.run(n,60)
    print('Finished loading notebook ' + n)
```

Comment: Are you running python files? Why not import them?

Comment: They are python notebooks located on the same databricks S3 instance as this file. They load correctly when I run them individually but it would be nice to load them all at once. I am not sure how that would be done given they are in a variety of cloud based folder locations. The files need to be not only loaded but run with the load.

Comment: Note: you dont need parenthesis around strings. I was just using it to show how to use arguments for each file

Comment: There is a difference between them - %run executes code in the current context, while dbutils is Indepedent, executed as tasks… plus there is an overhead related to triggering of the tasks

Comment: The short answer is NO, you cannot run more than a single `%run` statement within a cell. Also to answer @OneCricketeer you cannot use `import`. `import` requires that your package(s) or files are either store within of the standard python library otherwise you'll have to explicitly specify the path which `import` cannot parse. Databricks notebooks are stored within the node and there's no way to obtain their path except using `%run`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, only first `%` "command" is executable in any cell.

To programmatically run a notebook, take a look at [`dbutils.notebook.run`](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api)

Example

```
notebooks = [
   ('name', {'arg1': 'foo'}, ),
   ('other', {'arg1': 'bar'}, ) 
]

# for storing the values to call dbutils.notebook.exit function
notebook_ids = dict()

for n in notebooks:
    name = n[0]
    notebook_ids[name] = dbutils.notebook.run(name, 3600, n[1])
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: "module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'notebook'"

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it doesn't need the import? Hard to tell from the examples in the docs

Comment: usually there's no need to import `dbutils` is it readily available within your databricks environment.
`dbutils.notebook.run(path = "<path_to_notebook_within_your_user_account">, arguments=<dictionary_of_arguments>, timeout_seconds=<seconds>)`

Comment: a minor correction. missed a comma when making the list